# Is it possible to change the css file whenever the user reload the page?

Tags: css

what i want here is i have 4 css file and i want to change the css file whenever user refresh the page.

```css
<link href="assets/css/explorer-turquoise.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/explorer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/explorer-red.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/explorer-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Now whenever the user who come to my website without clicking any button or link change the css file dynamically. Is it possible to achieve it??

Comment: Yes. One possibility is to use a random number generator and a switch statement. What have you tried?

Comment: To bind those events you will need javascript.

Comment: Earlier  i was using when the user click in button then the css file will change now  my clients wants to change the css file whenever the user reload.

Comment: @J.Titus Can you help me with the code??

Comment: This cannot be done with pure HTML / CSS. However, it's very easy to do that with a back-end language. What back-end language are you using? Only JavaScript?

Comment: @ObsidianAge  I am using JS and Jquery. Can you help me with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript. Create an array with the names of your CSS files, select a random name from the array, create a `link` tag and set the `href` attribute to the random name, and append it to the page head.

```html
<script>
var sheets = ['explorer-turquoise','explorer','explorer-red','explorer-blue'],
        randSheet = sheets[Math.floor(Math.random()*sheets.length)];

    var newSheet = document.createElement('link');
    newSheet.href = '/assets/css/' + randSheet + '.css';
    newSheet.rel = 'stylesheet';

    document.head.appendChild(newSheet);
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work!!!  It should be under  $('document').ready(function(){}); right???  @Michael Coker

Comment: @PiyushSahay there are a number of ways you can use it. An easy way is to put it in your HTML in between `script` tags. I edited my answer to reflect that. You can put it anywhere on the page, but you may want to add it inside of `<head></head>` if you want it executed before the rest of the content loads. And it works - run my code snippet and inspect the html. It adds the stylesheet to the page.

Comment: Now its working!! But its not loading css file first. First the html page is open without css file then after few seconds the css fie is loading??